# unityでbuildしようとすると,errorが出ます

Tags: unity3d

unityの機械学習でerrorが出ました.
ml-agentsを使っています.
example_fileである,
3dball.appを作成しようとbuildを行っていると,

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00234] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

とでます.
調べてみると,たくさんの原因があるようですが,
他のteratailで出ているerrorとは違うようです.
具体的にどういう手順でbuildが完了してこの問題を解決することができるのかを教えてください.
unityのversion 2018 3.5f1
pythonのversion 3.6.8

その前に

```
Failed to update assembly 'Assets/ML-Agents/Plugins/Android/TensorFlowSharp.dll': Assembly reference folder does not exist: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\'.
```

と
注意書きが出ていました.
同じく,

```
Failed to update assembly 'Assets/ML-Agents/Plugins/Android/Java.Interop.dll': Assembly reference folder does not exist:
```

と出ていました.

Answer (score 2):

「Error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor」
[直訳]Playerのbuildでエラー。理由：scriptsでcompile errorsがあったため」
というメッセージですから、Playerのscriptを見直して、コンパイルエラーが出ないように修正してください。
コンパイルエラーは、プログラムコードが文法に違反していること等が原因で発生します。

> C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs　の190行目と、96行目

はエラーが発生したコードのある場所なので、注意してコードの見直しをしてください。